# Java Safelist Add <head> Tag to Allowed List

Tags: java, jsoup, whitelist

I want to create a whitelist to remove all html tags except **head**, **body** and **i** in a data. To do that I used Safelist class and jsoup library.

```
Safelist safe_list = Safelist.none();
safe_list.addTags(new String[] { "head", "body", "i"});
String data = "<head>Title here</head>
               <body>
                  <p><b> paragraph 1</b></p>
                  <p><i> paragraph 2</i></p>
               </body>";
String cleaned_data = Jsoup.clean(data,safe_list); 
System.out.println(cleaned_data);
```

The expected result was

```
<head>
 Title here
</head>
<body>
 paragraph 1 <i>paragraph 2</i>
</body>
```

but the result I got

```
<body>
 Title here paragraph 1 <i>paragraph 2</i>
</body>
```

Although head tag in the allowed list, it is removed from the data unlike body and i tag. What is the problem with head tag and what should I do to keep it in a data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. It may not be exact solution but it works in my case. The Jsoup official website has the following information:

> The cleaner and these safelists assume that you want to clean a body
> fragment of HTML (to add user supplied HTML into a templated page),
> and not to clean a full HTML document. If the latter is the case,
> either wrap the document HTML around the cleaned body HTML, or create
> a safelist that allows html and head elements as appropriate.

Because creating a safelist that allows html and head elements as appropriate doesn't work, I took the first suggestion:

```
Safelist safe_list = Safelist.none();
safe_list.addTags(new String[] {"body", "i"});
String data = "<body>
                  <p><b> paragraph 1</b></p>
                  <p><i> paragraph 2</i></p>
               </body>";
String cleaned_data = Jsoup.clean(data,safe_list); 
cleaned_data  = '<head>Title here</head>' + cleaned_data 
System.out.println(cleaned_data);
```

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Safelist.html

Answer (score 0):

Because the true structure for HTML file is:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

then your code should be written in this way:

```
Safelist safe_list = Safelist.none();
safe_list.addTags(new String[] { "head", "body", "i"});
String data = "<head><title>Title here</title></head>
               <body>
                  <p><b> paragraph 1</b></p>
                  <p><i> paragraph 2</i></p>
               </body>";
String cleaned_data = Jsoup.clean(data,safe_list); 
System.out.println(cleaned_data)
```

when you just use `<head> title hear</head>` then Jsoup think that the text between tag is "textNode".

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.